# Array from Yaml - Golang

Tags: arrays, go, multidimensional-array, yaml

I try to create configuration file for my go app what loops through some jobs.

My .yaml file looks like that (array):

```
jobToRun:
  - name: This is my first job to run
    sqlToRun: select 1 from some_table
    someVariable: 1

  - name: Other job to run
    sqlToRun: select 2 from some_table
    someVariable: 2
```

I have successfully imported the YAML file and created also structure.

```
    type Service struct {
        JobToRun []struct {
            Name         string `yaml:"name"`
            SQLToRun     string `yaml:"SqlToRun"`
            SomeVariable int    `yaml:"someVariable"`
        } `yaml:"jobToRun"`
    }
```

But I have no idea how to assign them to variable.

I tried some stuff what work with Json array-s but without any luck.

So I tried to print it to console without any luck:

```
println(service.JobToRun.name[0])
```

before that I tried to assign that SQL to my variable (which works if it is not an array item.

```
var sqlQuery = service.JobToRun.name[0]
```

And here is what I try to accomplish:

I take the Job parameters from .yaml array and run it.
I am using that kind of array in YAML because it is easiest way to add new jobs.

Comment: I only see a **single** dimension array of `struct`s. Where are the other dimensions? Please use a spell-checker on your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah as soon as i posted it i facepalmed.

```
println(service.JobToRun[0].Name)
```

so the reason was that "JobToRun is an array not "Name"